# Altair: How to use another column as a bar chart label?

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I'd like to have another dataframe column as the label of my bar chart. I thought that using `labelExpr` and `datum` construct would work, but nothing is displayed.

I simplified the problem as:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bar','foo'],
                       "another": ['a', 'b'],
                      'value':[10,20]})
    
    (alt.Chart(df, height=250, width=375).mark_bar()
     .encode(x=alt.X('name', axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="datum.another")), 
             y='value')
            
    )
```

The output is empty:

[image: chart with no labels]

I tried some variations like `labelExpr=alt.datum.another` but it is still empty.

Is it possible to do it without another layer?

Answer (score 0):

If the entries of the other column are a perfect one-to-one mapping to the entries of the first, the best way to do this is to use `another` directly in the encoding, adjusting the title if necessary:

```python
(alt.Chart(df, height=250, width=375).mark_bar()
  .encode(x=alt.X('another', title='name'),
          y='value')
)
```

If the other column does not have a direct one-to-one mapping to the first, then I don't think your question is well-posed, because there would not be a single unique entry to use for each label.

Comment: I believe it is a one-to-one matching. In the non simplified version, I have multiple charts. linked using a selector. The selector uses an id column that is present in all dataframes. I want to display a name column instead, but would still need the id to filter the other charts.

Comment: Try using the the id column in a `detail` encoding.